# Promise<Element> is not a valid JSX element, converting Promise<Element> to Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, jsx

I'm trying to use the `Item` component, but it gives this error:

```
(alias) const Item: (id: string) => Promise<JSX.Element>
import Item
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
'Item' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Promise<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key ts(2786)
```

The Item component is like this:

```js
const Item = async (id: string) => {    
    const itemData = await getItemData(id);

    return (<Button className="item">
        <ItemContent name={itemData.name} description={itemData.description} />
    </Button>);
}
```

The `getItemData` function is like this:

```js
async function getItemData(item: string) {

    if (item === "") {
        return {
            name: "Error",
            description: "Couldn't fetch the latest items :( ..."
        }
    }

    const itemData = fetch("/api/items/getItem/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: item
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error("Failed to get item data");
    });

    const res = (await itemData).json();
    return res;

}
```

What can I do to convert `Promise<Element>` to `Element`, I tried `.then(res => res.json())`, it doesn't work, I tried typing the functions, it doesn't work either, whenever I try to use the `Item` component it just gives the error.

If it's important, I'm using React Next.js with Typescript

Comment: Because async functions ALWAYS returns a Promise.
So even though you return "res" which is Element. It will be wrapped into a Promise automatically and be a Promise<Element>

Comment: I think this might be worth reopening (and maybe editing) due to this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42292

Answer (score 17):

To use an async Server Component with TypeScript, ensure you are using TypeScript 5.1.3 or higher and @types/react 18.2.8 or higher.
it is from official [next documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#async-and-await-in-server-components)

[image]

Also I add typescript role before component:

```
{/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */}
```

[image]

Comment: This did it for me! For some reason, Yarn wasn't seeing the Typescript and @types/react updates. Even after that, I had to completely restart VS Code before it would stop highlighting the error inline.

Answer (score 5):

Install the latest version of typescript and @types/react with this command:

```
npm install typescript@latest @types/react@latest
```

it'll fix the issues.
After the installation make sure to restart your code editor. This solved the issue.
Also if the component has "use client" at the top remove it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the `GetItemData` function in the page.tsx, this is because the JSX or TSX functions do not support asynchrony. Here I give you an example assuming that the search is done from the parameter

```
async function getItemData(item: string) {

    if (item === "") {
        return {
            name: "Error",
            description: "Couldn't fetch the latest items :( ..."
        }
    }

    const itemData = fetch("/api/items/getItem/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: item
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error("Failed to get item data");
    });

    const res = (await itemData).json();
    return res;

}
export default async function Page({params}: Props) {
const data = await getItemData(params)
  return (
    <>
      <Item data={data} />
    </>
  )
}
```

```
const Item = (data: ItsProps) => {    
    return (
    <Button className="item">
        <ItemContent name={data.name} description={data.description} />
    </Button>);
}
```